# JSP file not loading in production but working correctly in development

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-web-services, jsp, aws-sdk

I have a jsp file for displaying a new tab on a webpage. The html in the jsp file is correctly being loaded and rendered in the beta environment, however in production the JSP file itself is not loading leading to the following error on console:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: AWS is not defined`

This is because I am using the aws-sdk in my javascript file, but the import for the same is in my jsp, which is not being loaded at all as I can see from my console page.

I do not have access to the Production host to check the host logs, so the intent of this question is just to see if others have faced a similar issue to this one and what was the cause behind the error. Thanks in advance!